# Why is this derivative giving me zero?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to calculate the second derivative of the logarithm of the function

```
Om[a_, b_][x_] := (Coth^4[x/2] - 1)*Coth^2[x/2]/(a*Coth^4[x/2] - b)
```

with respect to $x$. Where $x$ is the independent variable and $a$ and $b$ are constants. So I tried

```
D[Log[Om[1, 1][x]], {x, 2}]
```

but is returning 0. I don't know why. I'm just a beginner in Mathematica so surely there is something that I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your syntax for powers of a function is wrong. Use `Om[a_, b_][x_] := (Coth[x/2]^4 - 1)*Coth[x/2]^2/(a*Coth[x/2]^4 - b)`

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem.